# 'church organizations, interest groups, __ nonprofits', the appropriate conjunction

Tags: conjunctions

> Usually, volunteer trips are arranged by church organizations, human interest groups, __ non-profits.

Which one of 'and' and 'or' is more appropriate to be filled in the blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both words are possible.  English doesn't attempt to mirror formal logic in this example.

You can use "and" (meaning these three things together make a list), or you can use "or" (meaning that trips are usually organised by one, and no more than one, of these types of organisations)

This does lead to slight ambiguity, but it isn't a problem.

Comment: Thanks very much! So it does not involve grammatical things, but has something to do with the context. I looked back the passage and thought that ‘or’ would be more rational according to the context.

Comment: Yes, I agree that "or" is more rational, and "or" is completely acceptable, so feel free to use "or".  Be aware that "or" in this context would be interpreted as "exclusive or"